# Is there any way to execute many maven build one after the other in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-plugin, eclipse-juno

I work on several project which I often have to make maven-install on them.
Is there a way to execute many maven build one after the other on many projects ?
I hope i'm understandable.

Thanks for help

Comment: If you want to trigger upstream builds based on updated dependencies, this can be accomplished with a continuous integration server such as Jenkins. http://jenkins-ci.org/

Answer (score 0):

I was too looking for that.
But didn't get satisfied on Creating just a new main maven project and
add all other projects to build as its modules project.

This way I could trigger all the projects builds by triggering just main project build.
But still, that wasn't digestable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can script that and use the -f switch of maven to specify which pom to build one after the other...

If you want to stick with maven, you can make a dedicated pom for invoking the sequence of your build by using the maven exec plugin. But this results a naaasty pom. Use it as last resort, because plugins should be used only once in one phase of the maven lifecycle. In certain cases it might be handy, e.g. you want to be able to run your build on different platforms and don't want to script with python, etc..):

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>mvn</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-DskipTests=true</argument>
                    <argument>-f</argument>
                    <argument>${basedir}/relative/path/to/other/module/pom.xml</argument>
                    <argument>clean</argument>
                    <argument>install</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>mvn</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-DskipTests=true</argument>
                    <argument>-f</argument>
                    <argument>${basedir}/relative/path/to/some/other/module/pom.xml</argument>
                    <argument>clean</argument>
                    <argument>install</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
<build>

<pluginManagement>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>process-resources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
<pluginManagement>
```